# How do you loop through an array and only extract key:value that are specific values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I would like to loop through an existing object and only extract specific keys to add to a new array.

The object looks like:

```
let lyricsData = {
   "success": true;
   "length": 50;
   "result": [
       {
         "id_track": 123,
         "haslyrics": true,
         "id_artrist": 234,
       },
       {
         "id_track": 567,
         "haslyrics": false,
         "id_artrist": 678,
    }
  ]
}
```

I would only like to extract the results **if "haslyrics" is true**.

This is the block of code I've come up with:

```
1  function findHasLyrics(lyricsData) {
2      if (lyricsData.length === 0) {
3          console.log("findHasLyrics", null);
4      } else {
5          let hasLyricsTrue = [];
6          for (let i=0; i<lyricsData.length; i++) {
7              if (lyricsData.result[i].haslyrics === true) {
8                  hasLyricsTrue.push(lyricsData.result[i]);
9              };
10             console.log("findHasLyrics", hasLyricsTrue);
11         };
12     };
13 };
```

Where is the code breaking? And how would I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

***SOLUTION (EDITED). Thanks @StepUp and @Ankita.***

I needed to keep the if-else statements. The lyricsData is dynamic and sometimes the length is 0. In that case, I need to pass a null through a function.

```
function findHasLyrics(lyricsData) {
    if (lyricsData.length === 0) {
        displayLyricsApi(null);
    } else {
        function findHasLyrics(lyricsData) {
            return lyricsData.result.filter(f => f.haslyrics)
    };
        formatQueryLyrics(findHasLyrics(lyricsData));
    };
}
```

Comment: A much simpler way to solve this problem would be to use filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `filter` method:

```
lyricsData.result.filter(f=> f.haslyrics)
```

in your case:

```
function findHasLyrics(lyricsData) {
    return return lyricsData.result.filter(f=> f.haslyrics);
};
```

An example:

```js
var data = {
    "success": true,
    "length": 50,
    "result": [{
        "id_track": 123,
        "haslyrics": true,
        "id_artrist": 234,
      },
      {
        "id_track": 567,
        "haslyrics": false,
        "id_artrist": 678,
      }
    ]
  };

 function findHasLyrics(lyricsData) {
    return lyricsData.result.filter(f=> f.haslyrics)
};

console.log(findHasLyrics(data));
```

Comment: Hey @StepUp, where would the filter method be applied? Thanks.

Comment: I needed to include the if else statements. The lyricsData is dynamic and at times, I'm given a length of 0. In the scenario length is 0, I need to log a null.

`function findHasLyrics(lyricsData) {
    if (lyricsData.length === 0) {
        console.log("findHasLyrics", null);
    } else {
        function findHasLyrics(lyricsData) {
            return lyricsData.result.filter(f => f.haslyrics)
    };
        console.log(findHasLyrics(lyricsData));
    };
}`

This was my final line of code. And it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Array.filter()` to filter the array with those objects that has `haslyrics` value as `true`. You can avoid the custom loops and logic with that function.

```js
var obj = {
   "success": true,
   "length": 50,
   "result": [
       {
         "id_track": 123,
         "haslyrics": true,
         "id_artrist": 234,
       },
       {
         "id_track": 567,
         "haslyrics": false,
         "id_artrist": 678,
    }
  ]
};

var res = obj.result.filter(({haslyrics}) => haslyrics);
console.log(res);
```

In your code you can update this way:

```js
function findHasLyrics(lyricsData) {
  if (lyricsData.length === 0) {
    console.log("findHasLyrics", null);
  } else {
    var res = lyricsData.result.filter(({haslyrics}) => haslyrics);
    console.log(res);
  };
};


var obj = {
  "success": true,
  "length": 50,
  "result": [{
      "id_track": 123,
      "haslyrics": true,
      "id_artrist": 234,
    },
    {
      "id_track": 567,
      "haslyrics": false,
      "id_artrist": 678,
    }
  ]
};

findHasLyrics(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you've made an easy to make mistake in the `for` signature, [docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

The second argument you're using doesn't return an Integer (number), `lyricsData.result` is an array, you want to return its `.length`, i.e:

```
for (let i=0; i<lyricsData.result.length; i++) {
  ...
}
```

However, I would advise you to use `.filter` as others have already suggested.